# View exception details in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, devexpress

I've started working on an old project, where `WinForms` application uses `DevExpress` controls, for example `DataGrid`.

The program window contains another multiple windows, and when I'm minimizing some of them, I get an Unhandled Application Exception with `Attempted to divide by zero.` in details. I want to know what causes this exception, but when I run the project in `Debug` mode in `Visual Studio` (2005 version), it does not react in any way to this exception.

Is there a way to find out the reason this exception is thrown?

Comment: And if you run it in Release mode? (you can still do some debugging then!)

Comment: Still the same result:(.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.  If you see DevExpress code in the stack trace then you'll need to contact them for support.

Comment: How can I do this? The only message I get now is the following: http://i.imgur.com/6Ns9C.png

Comment: It seems that the problem is not reproduced in older version of the Devexpress library: 7.2.1 (I have 7.2.5), so I guess the reason of this exception is in Devexpress control. But I though that it was possible to view debug info even for external libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable such exceptions in

> Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Also

> Also, it is a good idea to turn off the Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->Enable Just My Code option.

Comment: Thank you, I enabled all thrown exceptions: http://i.imgur.com/RvkB1.png , but result is still the same.

Comment: This is very strange as for me... Try to subscribe for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event, create a break point and see whether it handles

Comment: From what I found on the internet, some devexpress controls could cause such exception when resizing the window. I think that minimizing is something like resizing. Should the Visual Studio cath exceptions thrown by external lirary controls?

Comment: @MyUserName, sure, are you tried to enable all another checkboxes along with CLR Exceptions?

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to turn off the Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->Enable Just My Code option.  Does it help you to catch this exception in the debugger?

Comment: @MyUserName - yes If you are minimizing the form you would also be resizing the form.  As for your error.  As suggested I would contact their support department for assistance.

Comment: @Thank you for your help. I just wanted to get some more information about error before asking the support.

Comment: @DevExpress - Yes, enabling this option helped. I've got http://i.imgur.com/BofZe.png error with stack trace 'at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.VGridControlBase.OnResize(EventArgs e)'. I also checked the project on another computer (win7 x64) with the same control version (7.2.5.0), and it also had this error. However, the project with older version, 7.2.1, works fine.

Comment: it might be a problem of this particular build.  Most likely, it is fixed in a newer version of our controls.  However, 72.4 is the way too old and I can only suggest that you install a modern version.

Comment: @sll - I think you might add 'turn off the Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->Enable Just My Code' to your answer and I'll mark it as correct.